# Spark Data Loadling Issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting **IndexOutOfBoundException** while doing following operation in spark-shell

```
val input = sc.textFile("demo.txt")
b.collect
```

Both of above functions are working fine .

```
val out = input.map(_.split(",")).map(r => r(1))
```

Getting OutOfBoundException for above line

demo.txt is looks like this:(Header :- Name,Gender,age)

```
Danial,,14
,Male,18
Hema,,
```

With pig same file is working without any issue!!

Comment: What is `b`? Anyway, you probably have an empty line. `b.filter(_.nonEmpty)`

Comment: Typo Error !! typed b instead of "input". input file does not have any empty line. Getting same error even after including filter condition : input.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.split(",")).map(r => r(1)).collect

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out yourself, just start the Scala console and enter your sample lines.

```
scala> "Danial,,14".split(",")
res0: Array[String] = Array(Danial, "", 14)

scala> ",Male,18".split(",")
res1: Array[String] = Array("", Male, 18)

scala> "Hema,,".split(",")
res2: Array[String] = Array(Hema)
```

So ooops, the last line doesn't work. Add the number of expected columns to split:

```
scala> "Hema,,".split(",", 3)
res3: Array[String] = Array(Hema, "", "")
```

or even better, write a real parser. String.split isn't suitable for production code.

Comment: Thanks @Marius!! Its working perfecltly when I am specifying number of expected columns. Yes agree with your point custom parser is the best solution.

Comment: You could also use -1 for the argument instead of 3.